# How to modify a List between methods?

Tags: java

How do I modify "list" passed into validCell, in validCell, then return the modified list?  validCell takes the parameters and checks to see if a path of cells to spell out "word" can be found from the starting point given by r & c of the for loop in cellsForWord.  I don't think what I have is correct.

```
public class GoodWordOnBoardFinder implements IWordOnBoardFinder {

@Override
public List<BoardCell> cellsForWord(BoggleBoard board, String word) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<BoardCell> list = new ArrayList<BoardCell>();
    //Loop through each cell on board to find a starting point
       for(int r=0; r < board.size(); r++)
       {
           for(int c=0; c < board.size(); c++)
           {
              if(validCell(board, r, c, list, word, 0))
                  return list;
                   //***HOW to get populated list NOT Blank list???
           }
       }
    return null;
}
public boolean validCell(BoggleBoard theBoard, int row, int col, List<BoardCell> cList, String theWord, int letterIndex ){

    BoardCell cell = new BoardCell(row, col);

   String letter = theWord.substring(letterIndex, letterIndex+1);
    //Check the whole world has been found
   if(letterIndex >= theWord.length())
       return true;

   //Check if row or column is off the board
   if(row > theBoard.size() || col > theBoard.size())
       return false;
   //Check if cell has already been visited
   if(cList.contains(cell))
       return false;
   //Check if cell face isn't the letter we're looking for
   if(!theBoard.getFace(row, col).equals(letter))
   {
       //Make sure the letter isn't a Q bc Boggle is special
       if(!(theBoard.getFace(row, col).equals("Qu") && letter.equals("q")))
           return true;
   }
   cList.add(cell); 

  //Check all neighboring cells for letters of the word
  int[] rdelta = {-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
  int[] cdelta = {-1, 0, 1,-1, 1,-1, 0, 1};
  for(int k=0; k < rdelta.length; k++){
    if (validCell(theBoard, row+rdelta[k], col+cdelta[k], cList, theWord, letterIndex+1))
        return true;
   }
  cList.remove(cell);
return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Objects are passed byval (see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)).  This essentially means that a reference to the object itself is passed in, and translated back into the original object, not a copy of the object.  You can just modify list and not worry about returning it, as any modifications will be kept.

```
Example:
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("Test 1");
OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(test);
...
otherClass.modifyList(test);
...
System.out.println(test.size());
```

In this example, `modifyList` will hypothetically add another string to the passed in list.

Comment: Everything in java is pass by value. Read second answer to understand how it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: I believe what I said is still correct.  The effect is passing by value, as in from the programmer's perspective, it's byval.  However, at its core, it's byref.  Hence the answer by @erlando.

Corrected my post none-the-less.

Comment: Yes, I didn't complain your answer is wrong, but only one word was wrong. Now you corrected it. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make `cList` inside the validCell will automatically be reflected to the original list.

Java is pass by value: In this case it is passing the value of the reference. So both will be pointing to the same object. Any changes made in validCell to `cList` will reflect on `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the list into a class member. Then you don't have to pass it to the methods:

```
public class GoodWordOnBoardFinder implements IWordOnBoardFinder {

   // The board
   List<BoardCell> board;

   // methods
   public boolean validCell(BoggleBoard theBoard, int row, int col, String theWord, int letterIndex ){
     // access/modify the board (= what you called cList)
   }
}
```